# Define a function on assembly in different compilers

Tags: c++, performance, inline-assembly

Until now, I used inline `asm` with clobbering what it is not the best choice to get good performance. I am starting with assembly, but I am programing in my machine (GCC), but the result code is to run in other on (ICC), both in 64 bit (Sandy Bridge & Haswell).

To call a function without arguments we can do it with a `CALL`, but I do not understand too well how to call a function with arguments, and because of that I am trying use an inline `__asm__` inside of all function. It is a good choice?

My function:

```
void add_N(size_t *cnum, size_t *ap, size_t *bp, long &n, unsigned int &c){

    __asm__(
        //Insert my code here
    );

}
```

---

And when I see the **disassembly** (with GCC), I have:

```
add_N(unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, long&, unsigned int&):
0x100001ff0 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
0x100001ff1 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100001ff4 <+4>:  movq   %rdi, -0x8(%rbp)
0x100001ff8 <+8>:  movq   %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0x100001ffc <+12>: movq   %rdx, -0x18(%rbp)
0x100002000 <+16>: movq   %rcx, -0x20(%rbp)
0x100002004 <+20>: movq   %r8, -0x28(%rbp)
0x100002008 <+24>: popq   %rbp
0x100002009 <+25>: retq
```

I understand what is happening.. Will different compilers/microarchitectures always associate the same registers addresses if the function signature be the same?

---

Then put some code inside of my function (NOT `__ASM__` CODE), and the desassembly `PUSH` a lot of registers. Why did it happen? Why didn't I need to push `%rax` and `%rsi` (for example), and need to push `r13`, `r14` and `r15`? 
If I need to push the `r**` registers, can I do in the `inline __asm__`?

```
0x100001ea0 <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
0x100001ea1 <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100001ea4 <+4>:   pushq  %r15
0x100001ea6 <+6>:   pushq  %r14
0x100001ea8 <+8>:   pushq  %r13
0x100001eaa <+10>:  pushq  %r12
0x100001eac <+12>:  pushq  %rbx
0x100001ead <+13>:  movq   %rdi, -0x30(%rbp)
0x100001eb1 <+17>:  movq   %rsi, -0x38(%rbp)
0x100001eb5 <+21>:  movq   %rdx, -0x40(%rbp)
0x100001eb9 <+25>:  movq   %rcx, -0x48(%rbp)
0x100001ebd <+29>:  movq   %r8, -0x50(%rbp)
```

Comment: The `jmp` is an unconditional *jump*, not a *call*. If you do a `jmp` to a function which then uses a `ret` instruction to return, the stack won't be set up correctly to return and you will have some very weird behavior because the `ret` instruction will jump to some unknown location.

Comment: Thank you, I said that because I read it in other place..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the last question - yes, it will use the same register for parameters as long as they use the same ABI. The Linux x86_64 ABI is defined here: http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf and all compilers have to conform to it. Specifically you are interested in page 16 - Parameters Passing.

Windows have slightly different ABI I believe. So you cannot run your program or library compiled on Linux and run on Windows for example (there are some additional reasons for that though).

For details about gcc inline assembly check some existing tutorial as it's quite long topic. This is good start: http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rmiyagi-inline-asm.txt

Comment: Thank you, can you see a doubt that showed up int the meantime?

Comment: @HélderGonçalves : it would be quite difficult and long task to explain the inline assembly with gcc. It's better to take a look at some tutorial like this: http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/rmiyagi-inline-asm.txt

Comment: I don't believe that's quite correct (that the same registers will /always/ be used for the parameters).  For example if the function gets inlined, I don't believe you will find the parameters where you expect.  Also, if you use the -fwhole-program optimization, gcc may decide that the parameters aren't used (as far as it can see) and won't pass them.  What OP is proposing is risky, and I wouldn't depend on it.  Creating an 'extern' asm routine and linking it in should get the behavior he wants/expects.  If you must use inline asm, use #ifdef to detect the various supported compilers.